# Cannot stat 'direction', permission denied when permission's are set

Tags: server, permissions, nginx

Bear with me I am still new to Linux. I have a web server that is trying to access a public folder under a users account.

### Problem

I am running an nginx server that is trying to access the maintenance page within an applications shared public folder and receives permission denied errors.

### Basics

- Application user: `quotr` and primary group: `app`
- Webserver user: `ubuntu` and primary group: `www-data`
- Application home: `/home/quotr/app`
- Application shared public folder: `/home/quotr/app/shared`
- Absolute path of maintenance file: `/home/quotr/app/shared/public/system/maintenance.html`

### Groups:

I initially only added the `www-data` group to the `app` group hoping to fix the issue. When that didn't work, I also added the group going the other way.

```
www-data:x:33:apache,quotr
ubuntu:x:1000:
app:x:1001:quotr,ubuntu,www-data
```

### Ownership

The ownership for the whole application tree belong to `quotr:app`. When I started receiving the permission problems, I changed the ownership along `public/system/maintenance.html` portion of the path to the maintenance page (`/home/quotr/app/shared/public/system/maintenance.html`) to `quotr:www-data`.

### Permissions

Starting at `/var/www/quotr-public` and working our way down:

```
# ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 4 quotr www-data 4096 Mar  3 21:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 quotr www-data 4096 Mar  3 21:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 quotr www-data 4096 Mar  4 16:00 assets
drwxr-xr-x 3 quotr www-data 4096 Mar  4 19:03 system

# cd to system ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 3 quotr www-data 4096 Mar  4 19:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 quotr www-data 4096 Mar  3 21:49 ..
-rwxr-x--- 1 quotr www-data 3004 Mar  4 19:03 maintenance.html
drwxr-xr-x 3 quotr www-data 4096 Mar  3 21:51 pictures
```

### Testing

I am testing the permissions using the following command:

```
sudo -u www-data stat /home/quotr/app/shared/public/
```

which results in permission denied.

### Last Ditch

As a last ditch attempt, I created the following symlink:

```
quotr-public -> /home/quotr/app/shared/public/
```

Which I am able to run the following successfully but no deeper:

```
sudo -u www-data stat /var/www/quotr-public
```

I am at a complete loss of what the problem is at this point. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

### Edit 1

I have continued farting around with permissions so these might be a little difference, but please find below the output requested.
Output of 'namei -lx /home/quotr/app/shared/public/system/maintenance.html'

```
Drwxr-xr-x root  root     /
drwxr-xr-x root  root     home
drwx------ quotr app      quotr
drwxr-xr-x quotr app      app
drwxr-xr-x quotr www-data shared
drwxr-xr-x quotr www-data public
drwxr-xr-x quotr www-data system
-rw-r--r-- quotr app      maintenance.html
```

Output of 'namei -lx /var/www/quotr-public/system/maintenance.html '

```
Drwxr-xr-x root   root     /
drwxr-xr-x root   root     var
drwxrwsr-x root   www-data www
lrwxrwxrwx ubuntu www-data quotr-public -> /home/quotr/app/shared/public/
Drwxr-xr-x root   root       /
drwxr-xr-x root   root       home
drwx------ quotr  app        quotr
drwxr-xr-x quotr  app        app
drwxr-xr-x quotr  www-data   shared
drwxr-xr-x quotr  www-data   public
drwxr-xr-x quotr  www-data system
-rw-r--r-- quotr  app      maintenance.html
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add the output of `namei -lx /home/quotr/app/shared/public/system/maintenance.html` please.

Comment: There's your problem. `/home/quotr` has no execute permissions for others.

Comment: even though www-data belongs to the app group?

Comment: Unfortunately I added the permission via chmod o+x /home/quotr but it still cannot access it

Comment: Is `FollowSymlinks` enabled in Apache's options?

Comment: Yes I have tried 'disable_symlinks off;' as the first and last line within the http block of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Zanna Unfortunately I didn't nor have I had time to look into this again. I will be in the coming weeks though and I'll update it once I figure it out.

Thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost had it there with help from muru.  All folders in the tree do need to be executable by www-data.  Since the quotr folder is owned by the app group and www-data is in the app group, it'd be better to give exec to the group instead of others:

```
chmod g+x quotr
```

As a side suggestion... 
I have built several websites with nginx as www-data.  What has worked well for me is to let www-data own everything as user and group.  Then I add my user & whoever else needs access to the www-data group.

Comment: `o+x` gives permission to "others" ie to everyone. If everyone has permission then granting group permission will not help ;)

Comment: Indeed... others are not really "others" at all; they are actually "everyone". Hmmm.. never though of it that way.  Ok then! I updated with your input Zanna, thks.

Comment: But this does not answer the question :(

Comment: Thank you, this actually ended up being the problem. Unfortunately I forgot to check this post first and found it out myself.